# Data validation on ShowDialog window in WPF

Tags: wpf, validation, idataerrorinfo, showdialog

I have a window that I display as ShowDialog
in the window I have some textboxes binding to object that implement INotifyPropertyChannges and IDataErrorInfo.
I want that the OK button will enabled just if all thextboxes validted
and I want that just if the user click on OK buton the next move will occur.

I can bind the button to ICommand and check the textboxes valitation in CanExcute() but then what can I do in the Excute? the object dont know about the window.
I can also check the textboxes valitation and then raise event that all valid and enable the OK button but then there will be dupliacte code because I checked already in the IDataErrorInfo implmention.

So what is the right way?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You CanExecute should look like this.

```
   public bool CanExecuteOK        
   {
        get
        {
              if (DataModelToValidate.Error == null && DataModelToValidate.Errors.Count == 0) return true;
              else return false;
        }
   }
```

Here Error and Errors properties are nothing but Wrapper over this[string propertyName] (implemented implicitly for IDataErrorInfo).

Here is Sample Model Class:

```
    public class SampleModel: IDataErrorInfo, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public SampleModel()
        {
            this.Errors = new System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<string>();
        }
        private string _SomeProperty = string.Empty;
        public string SomeProperty
        {
            get
            {
                return _SomeProperty;

            }
            set
            {
                if (value != _SomeProperty)
                {
                    _SomeProperty= value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged("SomeProperty");
                }
            }
        }
....
....
        //this keeps track of all errors in current data model object
        public System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<string> Errors { get; private set; }
        //Implicit for IDataErrorInfo
        public string Error
        {
            get
            {
                return this[string.Empty];
            }
        }

        public string this[string propertyName]
        {
            get
            {

                string result = string.Empty;
                propertyName = propertyName ?? string.Empty;

                if (propertyName == string.Empty || propertyName == "SomeProperty")
                {
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.SomeProperty))
                    {
                        result = "SomeProperty cannot be blank";
                        if (!this.Errors.Contains(result)) this.Errors.Add(result);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (this.Errors.Contains("SomeProperty cannot be blank")) this.Errors.Remove("SomeProperty cannot be blank");
                    }
                }
......
      return result;
    }
```

Comment: thanks for the answer! but how Can I enable the button an what can I do in the ExecuteOk? the SampleModel dont know about the window.

Comment: The CanExecuteOK will do that for you. you need not worry about it. If CanExecuteOK returns false your button will be disabled automatically and if true, it will be enabled. Recall that for command binding you will need to implement 2 methods. CanExecuteOK and ExecuteOK. CanExecute will tell when to enable/disable and ExecuteOK will what to do.